# Which DLC works in multiplayer?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

Particularly, which DLC isn't explicitly intended for multiplayer but works in multiplayer?

I know that the [Agility Skill DLC](http://store.steampowered.com/app/208802/) is like this. And I think both the [Pistol Burst](http://store.steampowered.com/app/208804/) DLC and the [Pistol Silencer](http://store.steampowered.com/app/208805/) DLC are like this too, but I can't test it without buying them, so I'm hoping someone who has already bought them can say for sure.